# Why is RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter not giving any chunk overlap?

Tags: python, langchain, py-langchain

I am trying to create chunks (max) 350 characters long with 100 chunk overlap.

I understand that `chunk_size` is an upper limit, so I may get chunks shorter than that. But why am I not getting any `chunk_overlap`?

Is it because the overlap also has to split on one of the separator chars? So it's 100 chars chunk_overlap if there is a `separator` within 100 chars of the split that it can split on?

```py
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter

some_text = """When writing documents, writers will use document structure to group content. \
This can convey to the reader, which idea's are related. For example, closely related ideas \
are in sentances. Similar ideas are in paragraphs. Paragraphs form a document. \n\n  \
Paragraphs are often delimited with a carriage return or two carriage returns. \
Carriage returns are the "backslash n" you see embedded in this string. \
Sentences have a period at the end, but also, have a space.\
and words are separated by space."""

r_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
    chunk_size=350,
    chunk_overlap=100,
    separators=["\n\n", "\n", "(?<=\. )", " ", ""]
)
x = r_splitter.split_text(some_text)
print(x)
for thing in x:
    print(len(thing))
```

Output

```
["When writing documents, writers will use document structure to group content. This can convey to the reader, which idea's are related. For example, closely related ideas are in sentances. Similar ideas are in paragraphs. Paragraphs form a document.", 
'Paragraphs are often delimited with a carriage return or two carriage returns. Carriage returns are the "backslash n" you see embedded in this string. Sentences have a period at the end, but also, have a space.and words are separated by space.']
248
243
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?I have the same question

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 3):

I found that RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter will not overlap chunks that are split by a separator, like how you have it:
`separators=["\n\n", "\n", "(?<=\. )", " ", ""]`

What's happening is that each of your two paragraphs is being made into its own whole chunk due to the `\n\n` separator. Thus these chunks are considered separate and will not generate overlap. If you had a paragraph that was greater than your 350 chunk size (or if your chunk size was smaller), the paragraph would get split into multiple chunks, and those chunks would have overlap.

I assume the package's logic is that, since you are purposefully semantically separating those paragraphs, you wouldn't *want* them to have their messages overlapped. If it is something you want, I'd recommend removing the relevant separators.

Note: My answer breaks down a little when you consider that `" "` is a separator as well. You'd think that would make each word its own chunk. I don't understand that part yet.

Comment: Yeah it does break down a bit when you think about `" "`...